# Client configuration to consume WCF JSON web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, json

I have configured the web service to use Json as described on this blog: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/164419.aspx and various other blogs, but I couldn't create a client to consume this service. I tried various things, but invariably I got meaningless exceptions. What is the correct way to implement the (WCF I should add) client?

Comment: Is the service running in the same domain as the client? I ran into an issue where my service was running on domain other than my client and could never get them to communicate. Then it dawned on me, AJAX doesn't allow for cross domain communication, nativley.

Answer (score 46):

There seems to be a shortage of examples about how to write a WCF client for a JSON REST service. Everybody seems to use WCF for implementing the service but hardly ever for writing a client. So here's a rather complete example of the service (implementing a GET and a POST request) and the client.

### Service

**Service interface**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "/getcar/{id}")]
    Car GetCar(string id);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "/updatecar/{id}")]
    Car UpdateCar(string id, Car car);
}
```

**Service data structures**

```
[DataContract]
public class Car
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Make { get; set; }
}
```

**Service implementation**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public Car GetCar(string id)
    {
        return new Car { ID = int.Parse(id), Make = "Porsche" };
    }

    public Car UpdateCar(string f, Car car)
    {
        return car;
    }
}
```

**Service markup**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="JSONService.Service1"
    CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs"
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>   
</configuration>
```

### Client

And now the client. It reuses the interface `IService1` and the class `Car`. In addition, the following code and configuration is required.

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webby">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:57211/Service1.svc" name="Service1" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="JSONService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webby"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Program.cs**

```
public class Service1Client : ClientBase<IService1>, IService1
{
    public Car GetCar(string id)
    {
        return base.Channel.GetCar(id);
    }


    public Car UpdateCar(string id, Car car)
    {
        return base.Channel.UpdateCar(id, car);
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
        Car car = client.GetCar("1");
        car.Make = "Ferrari";
        car = client.UpdateCar("1", car);
    }
}
```

Have fun.

Comment: It is soooo true that client side implementation example are very rare on internet. It helped me solve my problem.

Comment: I have asked another question about accessing the HTTP status code in WCF client. Please can you see that and throw some light? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4677052/23671

Comment: I'm curious.  What is the point of hiding the REST service behind a RPC-based client proxy.  Why not just use SOAP?  By using WCF on the client like this, IMHO you have lost all the benefits that REST could bring.

Comment: This example is just a by-product of some experimenting when I was writing a WFC client for an already existing REST service using mainly JSON (implemented in Java). That service looks rather different and is almost exclusively read-only. And it has proven to be well adapted for it's purpose: to deliver data with the chosen degree of detail, in a compact format and in a single request. The clients are mobile phones with a limited bandwidth and often signification round-trip time. Fortunately, the service was not SOAP (too complex, too verbose). And the RPC-style proxies are just easy to use...

Comment: You do realize that its not REST though, right? RPC over HTTP can be valuable, but it will not realize the benefits that a REST architecture brings.

Comment: @DarrelMiller perhaps, but the model you are talking about is not always useful; RPC-HTTP is preferable in a lot of scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

What are the exceptions?  They may be meaningless to you, but some one around here might find them helpful in diagnosing your problem.  I use jQuery to make ajax request to a WCF service and the settup usually looks like this:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            type: "POST",
            processData: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            timeout: 5000,
            dataType: "json"
        });
        var data = { "value": 5 };

        AjaxPost("GetData", data, OnEndGetData, OnError);
    });

    function OnEndGetData(result) {
        alert(result.GetDataResult);
    }

    function OnError(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }

function AjaxPost(method, data, callback, error) {
    var stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
    var url = "Service1.svc/" + method;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: stringData,
        success: function(msg) {
            callback(msg);
        },
        error: error
    });
}
```

The JSON.stringify() can be found in the json.org script: http://www.json.org/js.html, and my sig for GetData method looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat =   WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string GetData(int value);
```

Comment: Hi, maybe I was not clear enough, but I was really trying to implement a WCF client inside a winform appication in C#, and not a web client.

Comment: And also I get an error for the line `$.ajax({` :  $ is not defined

Comment: Im not sure you can implement a JSON client without using a plain old WebClient or HttpRequest/Response setup.

The $ is part of jQuery.

Comment: What has this answer got to do with creating/configuring a WCF client??

Comment: @nashwan The question didnt specify what kind of wcf client.  I created a client using jquery and js.

Comment: @Mike_G you have described a JavaScript AJAX client not a WCF client.  (WCF is not the name of the server side... there are WCF services on the server side and WCF clients on the client side.  You can also consume a WCF service using another type of client, but that is not what the question is about).