# Accessing HTTP status code while using WCF client for accessing RESTful services

Tags: wcf, json, wcf-client, wcf-rest

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835839/client-configuration-to-consume-wcf-json-web-service/4535043#4535043), I am now able to successfully call a JSON RESTful service using a WCF client. But that service uses HTTP status codes to notify the result. I am not sure how I can access those status codes since I just receive an exception on client side while calling the service. Even the exception doesn't have HTTP status code property. It is just buried in the exception message itself.

[image]

So the question is, how to check/access the HTTP status code of response when the service is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick win, you can access the status code in the exception like this:

```
try
{
    client.DoSomething();  // call the REST service
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    if (x.InnerException is WebException)
    {
        WebException webException = x.InnerException as WebException;
        HttpWebResponse response = webException.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        Console.WriteLine("Status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

Maybe there's a solution with a message inspector. But I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without WCF would be to use the *HttpRequest* and *DataContractJsonSerializer* classes directly:

```
private T ExecuteRequest<T>(Uri uri, object data)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

    // If we have data, we use a POST request; otherwise just a GET request.
    if (data != null)
    {
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(data.GetType());
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        serializer.WriteObject(requestStream, data);
        requestStream.Close();
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    T result = (T)deserializer.ReadObject(responseStream);
    responseStream.Close();
    response.Close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I knew I could do it with plain HTTP requests but using WCF is easier. But your other answer does make sense.