# json with C# in a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, json, xml-rpc

I am looking at adding SMS abilities to my WCF service.  I found a cheap SMS service called [Penny SMS](http://www.pennysms.com/).

Their interface supports [json](https://www.pennysms.com/docs_json).  But I have no idea how to call it in my WCF service.

Here is the interface/example:

Sample JSON-RPC Request

```
{ "method": "send",
  "params": [
            "YOUR_API_KEY",
            "msg@mycompany.com",
            "5551231234",
            "Test Message from PENNY SMS"
            ]
}
```

How would I call that with C# from a WCF service?   What I am looking for is a way to wrap this into a method call.  Something like:

```
StaticSMSClass.SendSMS("1234567890", "My Message to send");
```

Note they also support an [XML-RPC API](http://www.pennysms.com/docs_xml) if that is more doable from C#.

UPDATE: I made a stab at creating a call myself, but it did not work.  I am going to post my attempt in a separate question and see if anyone has a way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to send a HTTP POST with the JSON message to the remote server. You can do this with [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx). You either build the JSON manually (the messages seem simple), or define types for it and use a [JSON serializer](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).

[MSDN has an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx), for your case it would look something like (untested):

```
string json = // Your JSON message
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://api.pennysms.com/jsonrpc");
request.Method = "POST";
var postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
request.ContentType = "text/json";
using(var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream()) 
{
    reqStream.Write(postData);
}
using(var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    // Response status is in response.StatusCode
    // Or you can read the response content using response.GetResponseStream();
}
```

Comment: Care to hazard an example of how to do this?

Comment: can it be wcf security applied?

Answer (score 2):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835839/client-configuration-to-consume-wcf-json-web-service/4535043#4535043) to the question *"Client configuration to consume WCF JSON web service"* for how the create a JSON client with WCF.

Answer (score 2):

The answers so far are good, but one additional thing you can take advantage of (since you are within a WCF service) is the use of DataContractJsonSerializer.

In particular, I refer to how you actually populate your JSON in the first line of driis's example.

```
string json = // Your JSON message
```

Now, one of the best ways to do this may be to create a new class with these members:

```
[DataContract]
class SomeType 
{
    [DataMember]
    string method;
    [DataMember]
    string[] params;
}
```

Then, just create an instance of SomeType every time and serialize it to JSON using the DataContractJsonSerializer every time you want to send over a piece of data. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx for how to use the DataContractJsonSerializer stand-alone.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Check the WCF REST API. They serve JSON, maybe they also can send JSON (in intra WCF solution it works). Maybe you have to construct the contract in wsdl to get the service running but maybe it works out.