# .Net & WCF - How to create REST instead of SOAP?

Tags: .net, json, rest, wcf

I created a couple of services, but they are all running as soap web services and return soap messages.

1- How can I make my wcf project to be restful instead of soap?

2- How can i make all services to return and expect json instead of xml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do at least two things:

- decorate your operation contracts (the service methods) with a `WebGet` or `WebInvoke` attribtue and define a URI template
- define a service endpoint that uses the `webHttpBinding` and a specific `webHttp` endpoint behavior

Other than that - you really don't need to do anything to get your REST service up and running.

Mind you: this is just "exposing" your current SOAP methods as REST - this is not the "proper" REST style of programming. To do that, you'd have to design your service from the beginning to be RESTful.

SOAP typically uses messages and methods - stuff like `GetCustomer`, `GetBalance` and so forth.

REST on the other hand thinks in resources - you have a `Customer` resource, and issuing an `HTTP GET` on that resource URI retrieves the customer, a `PUT` would insert a new customer, `POST` would update an existing customer, and `DELETE` (all HTTP verbs) will delete your customer. So in proper REST, you're not thinking in methods and procedures - you're thinking about how to expose resources and make those available to the consumer of your service.

Answer (score 1):

Another example of a WCF REST/Json service and client can be found in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835839/client-configuration-to-consume-wcf-json-web-service/4535043#4535043) to the question *"Client configuration to consume WCF JSON web service"*.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent section in the MSDN docs devoted to [a detailed analysis of how to "JSON-enable" your WCF services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412173.aspx). I recommend it as a starting point.

But before you read that, I recommend skimming [through the section on the WCF Web Http Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412169.aspx), since it builds up some foundational concepts that would be useful in understanding the JSON-enablement / AJAX-enablement topics of WCF described later.

Hope this helps!