# Create WCF Json/RESTful service client proxy

Tags: wcf, json, rest

here is my question: Is there any tool to generate one service client proxy when the service is Rest/Json? the service is WCF, and  one of the clients is WPF and i need this in order to create the tests with similar code than I test the classic Soap WCF services.

If not What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the service is WCF, you can use the svcutil.exe util to create a client even if you're using JSON or REST as the binding.

This thread has information on it:
[Client configuration to consume WCF JSON web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835839/client-configuration-to-consume-wcf-json-web-service)

Comment: The example you pointed to does not use svcutil to generate the client proxies. It manually creates a class based on ClientBase<IServiceContract>.  Either way client proxies are a terrible idea for consuming RESTful services.

Answer (score 8):

No, there isn't simply because there is no metadata with RESTful protocols such as you get the WSDL from SOAP.