# Cross-domain calling a WCF Service

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, web-services, cross-domain

I have a WCF service, this is a method which I'd to call:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    double?[] GetPoints(string tourname);
```

I checked by WCF Test Client, it works fine

So I need to call this method from html page. It should work from other computer that is cross-domain.

I wrote somethig using jQuery 1-6-2.min.js:

```
var varType;
var varUrl;
var varData;
var varContentType;
var varDataType;
var varProcessData;

function CallService() {
        alert("CallService");
                $.ajax({
                    type          : varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                    url           : varUrl, // Location of the service
                    data          : varData, //Data sent to server
                    contentType   : varContentType, // content type sent to server
                    dataType      : varDataType, //Expected data format from server
                    processdata   : varProcessData, //True or False
                    success       : function(msg) {//On Successfull service call
                    ServiceSucceeded(msg);                    
                    },
                    error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
                });
        }

function Start() {
    varType = "POST";
    varUrl = "http://localhost:1592/TourService.svc/GetPoints";
    varData = '{"tourname ":"customname"}';
    varContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    varDataType = "json";
    varProcessData = true; 
    CallService();
}

function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
    alert("ServiceSucceeded");
    alert(result);
}

function ServiceFailed(result) {
    alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
    varType = null;
    varUrl = null;
    varData = null;
    varContentType = null;
    varDataType = null;
    varProcessData = null;
}
```

However ServiceFailed function is invoked with message "Service call failed 0 error"

How to make a cross-domain calling of WCF service?(using jQuery or not)

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that cross-domain calling is the problem? And please better analyze where the error happens. The message "0 error" just shows that the original error message wasn't properly forward to the jQuery error callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to be using jSONP instead of jSON:

[Using jQuery & JSONP for cross-domain AJAX with WCF services](http://jasonkelly.net/2009/05/using-jquery-jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax-with-wcf-services/)

I'll provide a summary shortly in case this link disappears.

Also see the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more about how to use jSONP, jQuery & AJAX

Answer (score 1):

.net framework 4 for wcf has json call back inbuilt now ,

I think jquery1.5 onwards they added the following option , crossDomain , try the below code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "http://www.domain.com/page.aspx",
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    },
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg );
    }
});
```

Comment: @illya , if you are not using .net framework 4 , please follow this link , we used this and achieved what you are looking for http://jasonkelly.net/2009/05/using-jquery-jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax-with-wcf-services/

Comment: Which is the same as the link in my answer BTW

Comment: http://jasonkelly.net/2009/05/using-jquery-jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax-with-wcf-services/ is a broken link now.