# type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I have a java String variable *newTempTT* which holds the following:

```
myObject = {"VehicleID":"KL-9876","VehicleType":"Nissan","VehicleOwner":"Sanjiva"}
```

I would like to add this into a json object so i performed the following line of code:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(newTempTT);
```

There is no error message but when i run the program it says

"of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

What changes do I need to make in order to convert this string to a JSONObject.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include escape characters like this for every double quotes.

```
 String newTempTT = "myObject = {\"VehicleID\":\"KL-9876\",\"VehicleType\":\"Nissan\",\"VehicleOwner\":\"Sanjiva\"}";

JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(newTempTT);
```

Comment: could you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088119/not-sure-if-the-android-program-is-consuming-a-json-string 
and see if im passing a valid json string from my web service please

Comment: The thing is I don't know the asp.net and it's going over my head. But your problem seems minor to me. Are you sure you are getting correct json string from your asp side?

Comment: no friend, i think im getting the wrong json. I will look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc:

```
    Parameters: source - `A string beginning with { (left brace) and ending with } (right brace).` 
    Throws:
    JSONException - If there is a syntax error in the source string or a duplicated key.
```

Check if you are following this currently.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be encoding things to JSON yourself. Don't do this, let the library do it for you.